# Чтение объектов класса из файла в массив объектов класса

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Здесь два главных класса: класс Поезд и класс Билеты, класс Билеты наследует класс Поезд. Проблема в том, что не могу считать из файла ( в который уже записаны данные ) объекты класса, пыталась разными способами, но всегда какие-то ошибки. Помогите пожалуйста

```
class Train {// класс, описывающий поезд
protected:
    string number;
    string path;
    string date;
    string time;
    int cars;

public:

    Train() {
        number = "-";
        path = "-";
        date = "--.--.----";
        time = "--:--";
        cars = 0;
    }

    void set_train(string number, string path, string date, string time, int cars) {
        this->number = number;
        this->path = path;
        this->date = date;
        this->time = time;
        this->cars = cars;
    }

    void ScanTrain() {
        cout << "\nВведите сведения о поезде: \nНомер: ";
        cin >> number;
        cout << endl << "Путь: ";
        cin >> path;
        cout << endl << "Дата отправления: ";
        cin >> date;
        cout << endl << "Время отправления: ";
        cin >> time;
        cout << endl << "Количество вагонов: ";
        cin >> cars;
    }

    string get_train() const {
        return "\nНомер поезда: " + number + "\nНаправление движения поезда: " + path + "\nДата отправления: " + date + "\nВремя отправления: " + time + "\nКоличество вагонов: " + to_string(cars);
    }
    string get_train(string num) const {
        if (this->number == num) {
            return  "\nНомер поезда: " + number + "\nНаправление движения поезда: " + path + "\nДата отправления: " + date + "\nВремя отправления: " + time + "\nКоличество вагонов: " + to_string(cars);
        }
        else return "Нет такого поезда";
    }

    //геттеры и сеттеры
    void set_number(string number) {
        this->number = number;
    }
    string get_number() const {
        return number;
    }

    void set_path(string path) {
        this->path = path;
    }
    string get_path() const {
        return path;
    }

    void set_date(string date) {
        this->date = date;
    }
    string get_date() const {
        return date;
    }

    void set_time(string time) {
        this->time = time;
    }
    string get_time() const {
        return time;
    }

    void set_cars(int cars) {
        this->cars = cars;
    }
    int get_cars() const {
        return cars;
    }

} poezd[3];

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class Tickets : public Train {

protected:

    struct Carriage {//вложенная структура, описывающая вагон поезда
        int number_of_carriage;
        string type_of_carriage;
        int sits;


        Carriage() {
            number_of_carriage = 0;
            type_of_carriage = "-";
            sits = 0;
        }

        void ScanСarriage() {
            cout << "\nНомер вагона: ";
            cin >> number_of_carriage;
            cout << "\nТип вагона: ";
            cin >> type_of_carriage;
        }


        void set_number_of_carriage(int number_of_carriage) {
            this->number_of_carriage = number_of_carriage;
        }
        int get_number_of_carriage() const {
            return number_of_carriage;
        }

        void set_type_of_carriage(string type_of_carriage) {
            this->type_of_carriage = type_of_carriage;
        }
        string get_type_of_carriage() const {
            return type_of_carriage;
        }

        void set_sits(string type_of_carriage) {
            if (type_of_carriage == "купе") {
                this->sits = 36;
            }
            if (type_of_carriage == "плацкарт") {
                this->sits = 54;
            }
            if (type_of_carriage == "общий") {
                this->sits = 81;
            }
        }
        int get_sits() const {
            return sits;
        }

    };

    string price;

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    class Info {//вложенный класс, описывающий информацию о пассажире

    protected:
        string fio;
        int sit;

    public:


        Info() {
            fio = "-";
            sit = 0;
        }

        void ScanInfo() {
            cout << "\nВведите данные о пассажире: \nФИО: ";
            cin >> fio;
            cout << "\nМесто: ";
            cin >> sit;
        }

        void set_info(string fio, int sit) {
            this->fio = fio;
            this->sit = sit;
        }
        string get_info() const {
            return "\nСведения о пассажире: \nФИО: " + fio + "\nМесто: " + to_string(sit);
        }

        void set_fio(string fio) {
            this->fio = fio;
        }
        string get_fio() const {
            return "\nФИО пассажира: " + fio;
        }

        void set_sit(int sit) {
            this->sit = sit;
        } //надо понять, когда и где ее вызвать и проверить
        int get_sit() const {
            cout << "\nМесто: ";
            return sit;
        }

    };

    string number;
    Train train;
    Carriage carriage;
    Info data;

public:

    void read(ifstream *in) {
        in->read((char *)this, sizeof(Tickets));
        if (in->fail())
            cout << "read failed" << endl;
    }

    Tickets() {
        price = "00p.";
    }


    Tickets(string number, string path, string date, string time, int cars, int number_of_carriage, string type_of_carriage, int sits, string price,
        string fio, int sit) { // конструктор с параметрами
        //train.set_train(number, path, date, time);
        this->carriage.number_of_carriage = number_of_carriage;
        this->carriage.type_of_carriage = type_of_carriage;
        this->price = price;
        data.set_info(fio, sit);
    }

    /*Tickets() { // конструктор копирования

    }
    */

    ~Tickets() { // деструктор
        //cout << "\nСработал деструктор";
    }


    /*void deleteObj()

    { //Delete object from list

        cout << "Введите номер поезда" << endl;
        int temp;
        cin >> temp;
        bool find;

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if (temp == ticket[size].getPostavCode()) {
                ticket[size].show();
                find = true;
                g.erase(g.begin() + i);
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!find) cout << "Не удалось найти объект для удаления" << endl;

    }*/


    string get_price(string type_of_carriage, string priceK, string priceP, string priceO) const {
        if (type_of_carriage == "Купе") {
            return  priceK;
        }
        if (type_of_carriage == "Плацкарт") {
            return  priceP;
        }
        if (type_of_carriage == "Общий") {
            return  priceO;
        }
    }

    void set_price(string price) {
        this->price = price;
    }
    string get_price() const {
        return price;
    }



    /*void writeToFile(string pathtofile) {

        ofstream fout(pathtofile, ios_base::app); //запись в файл, ios_base - флаг режима для открытия файла
        Train train;

        fout << train.number << " " << flower.name << " " << carriage.type_of_carriage << " " << flower.family << " " << flower.country << " " << flower.goden << endl;

        fout.close();

    }

    void output() { //Output to file

        cout << "Введите имя файла с расширением" << endl;

        cin >> fname;

        for (int i = 0; i < garden.n; i++) {

            flower.writeToFile(name);

        }
    }

    void input() {

        cout << "Введите имя файла с расширением" << endl;

        cin >> fname;

        ifstream fin(fname); //чтение из файла

        int code;

        string name;

        string type;

        string family;

        string country;

        int goden;

        int left;

        int code_post;

        do {

            fin >> code >> name >> type >> family >> country >> goden >> left >> code_post;

        } while (!fin.eof());

        fin.close();

    }*/

    //void Scan() {
    //  string n, p, d, t, f, typec;
    //  int s, numberc;

    //  cout << "\nНомер поезда: ";
    //  cin >> number;
    //  /*cout << "\nНаправление движения поезда: ";
    //  cin >> p;
    //  cout << "\nДата отправления: ";
    //  cin >> d;
    //  cout << "\nВремя отправления: ";
    //  cin >> t;
    //  train.set_train(n, p, d, t);*/
    //  cout << "\nНомер вагона: ";
    //  cin >> carriage.number_of_carriage;
    //  cout << "\nТип вагона: ";
    //  cin >> carriage.type_of_carriage;

    //  cout << "\nЦена билета: ";
    //  cin >> price;
    //  cout << "\nФИО пассажира: ";
    //  cin >> f;
    //  cout << "\nМесто пассажира: ";
    //  cin >> s;
    //  data.set_info(f, s);
    //}

    //void Print(Train* t) {
    //  //train.get_train();
    //  cout << "\nНомер вагона: " << carriage.number_of_carriage
    //      << "\nТип вагона: " << carriage.type_of_carriage << "\nЦена билета: "
    //      << price;
    //  for (int n = 0; n < 10; n++) {

    //      if(t[n]->)

    //  }
    //  data.get_info();
    //  cout << "\n";
    //}
    void Print(string number) {
        cout << get_train(number);
        cout << "\nНомер вагона: " << get_number_of_carriage()
            << "\nТип вагона: " << get_type_of_carriage() << "\nЦена билета: "
            << price;
        cout << data.get_info();
        cout << "\n";
    }

    //для train
    /*string get_train() const {
        return train.get_train();
    }
    void set_number(string number) {
        set_number(number);
    }
    string get_number() const {
        return train.get_number();
    }
    void set_path(string path) {
        set_path(path);
    }
    string get_path() const {
        return train.get_path();
    }
    void set_date(string date) {
        set_date(date);
    }
    string get_date() const {
        return train.get_date();
    }
    void set_time(string time) {
        set_fio(time);
    }
    string get_time() const {
        return train.get_time();
    }
    */

    //для carriage
    void set_number_of_carriage(int number_of_carriage) {
        this->carriage.set_number_of_carriage(number_of_carriage);
    }
    int get_number_of_carriage() const {
        return carriage.get_number_of_carriage();
    }

    void set_type_of_carriage(string type_of_carriage) {
        this->carriage.set_type_of_carriage(type_of_carriage);
    }
    string get_type_of_carriage() const {
        return carriage.get_type_of_carriage();
    }

    void set_sits(string type_of_carriage) {
        this->carriage.set_sits(type_of_carriage);
    }
    int get_sits() const {
        return carriage.get_sits();
    }

    void Get_Carriage(Carriage carriage) {// ?????????????????????????????????????????????
        set_number_of_carriage(carriage.get_number_of_carriage());
        set_type_of_carriage(carriage.get_type_of_carriage());
    }

    void Get_Train() {
        this->set_number(train.get_number());
        this->set_path(train.get_path());
        this->set_date(train.get_date());
        this->set_time(train.get_time());
        this->set_cars(train.get_cars());
    }

    //для info
    void set_fio(string fio) {
        data.set_fio(fio);
    }
    string get_fio() const {
        return data.get_fio();
    }
    void set_sit(int sit) {
        data.set_sit(sit);
    }
    int get_sit() const {
        return data.get_sit();
    }



    void ScanCarriage() {
        carriage.ScanСarriage();
    }

    void ScanInfo() {
        data.ScanInfo();
    }

};


//поиск при покупке
void buying() {

    string pathtoT = "Tickets.txt";
    string pathtoBT = "BoughtTickets.txt";
    ifstream file;
    fstream boughtTickets;
    int size = 100000;
    Tickets *temp_tickets = new Tickets[size];

    string temp_path;
    string temp_date;

    cout << "\nНаправление движения поезда: ";
    cin >> temp_path;
    cout << "\nДата отправления поезда: ";
    cin >> temp_date;

    file.open(pathtoT);

    //Tickets tik;
    int s = 0;
```

> вот те способы, которыми я пыталась, к слову, с перегрузкой у меня тоже не получилось

```
    if (!file.is_open() && !boughtTickets.is_open()) {

        cout << "\nОшибка открытия файла!" << endl;

    }
    else {

        cout << "\nФайл успешно открыт!" << endl;
        while (true) {
            //file >> temp_tickets[s];
            //file.read((char*)&temp_tickets[s], sizeof(temp_tickets[s]));
            //temp_tickets[s].read(&file);
            temp_tickets[s].Print(temp_tickets[s].get_number());
            if (file.eof()) {
                break;
            }
            s++;

        }
```

> дальше код не нужен вроде, мне бы с этим разобраться

Comment: Хорошо спроектированная иерархия классов должна отражать отношения реальных объектов. Что общего у билета с поездом? Да ничего совершенно, у них нет ни единого общего свойства. От класса "поезд" можно произвести классы "грузовой состав", "дрезина", "электричка", но уж никак не "билет".

Comment: Выделите отдельно код который пишет (без закомментированных кусков), и код, который читает. В портянках кода мало кому интересно разбираться, особенно когда этот код никак не связан с вопросом. И еще желательно описать формат файла данных - что именно там должно находиться после вывода и в каком виде. И что там находится после работы вашей программы.